# RShiny: Why does htmlOutput prevents JavaScript from working?

Tags: javascript, html, r, shiny, shinyjs

I am builing a RShiny app where I need to create **vanilla/plain html buttons** and give basic functionality to them using **JavaScript**. In my original app I have a htmlOutput (or uiOutput) element containing these buttons (they are generated dynamically based on user input). Unfortunately JavaScript is not working properly inside this htmlOutput element and I cant figure out why. Please see my minimal reproducible example (app.R):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

# define ui
ui <- fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    tags$head(
        tags$script(
            HTML(
            "window.onload = function(){
            var coll = document.getElementsByClassName('testclass');
            var i;
            console.log(coll);
              for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
                  coll[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
                    alert('clicked');
                  });
              };
            };
            ")
            )
    ),
    mainPanel(
        # normal button (working)
        tags$button(
            type="button",
            class="testclass",
            "Click to alert (button inside main panel)"
        ),
        # html output button (not working)
        htmlOutput("html_out")
    )
)

# define server
server <- function(input, output) {

    # generate html output button (problematic with JS)
    output$html_out <- renderUI({
        tags$button(
            type="button",
            class="testclass",
            "Click to alert (button inside htmlOutput)"
        )
    })
}

# run app
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The tags$button() element is working without problem if it is added statically into the main panel. But if the same tags$button() element is added via the htmlOutput it is not working with the JavaScript code. Is there any explanation or workaround for that?

The only difference in the html output code is that the htmlOutput element is wrapped inside a div with class = "shiny-html-output shiny-bound-output". And I know that I usually shouls use actionButton() but in my case this is not possible.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Perhaps post the rendered output using view-source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the initial JS in `head` is run when the app starts but the second button isn't available immediately. you can add the JS code directly to the HTML code

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

# define ui
ui <- fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    tags$head(
        tags$script(
            HTML(
                "window.onload = function(){
            var coll = document.getElementsByClassName('testclass');
            var i;
            console.log(coll);
              for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
                  coll[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
                    alert('clicked');
                  });
              };
            };
            ")
        )
    ),
    mainPanel(
        # normal button (working)
        tags$button(
            type="button",
            class="testclass",
            "Click to alert (button inside main panel)"
        ),
        # html output button (not working)
        htmlOutput("html_out")
    )
)

# define server
server <- function(input, output) {
    
    # generate html output button (problematic with JS)
    output$html_out <- renderUI({
        tags$button(
            type="button",
            class="testclass",
            
            # ADD JS HERE
            onclick = "alert('clicked');",
            "Click to alert (button inside htmlOutput)"
        )
    })
}

# run app
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```